# pandas - the label [2018-01-15] is not in the [index]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi got problem with selecting data from data frame, 
i ve got dataframe with stock quotes with following index

```
dfq.index

DatetimeIndex(['1991-04-16', '1991-04-16', '1991-04-16', '1991-04-16',
               '1991-04-16', '1991-04-23', '1991-04-23', '1991-04-23',
               '1991-04-23', '1991-04-23',
               ...
               '2018-01-19', '2018-01-19', '2018-01-19', '2018-01-19',
               '2018-01-19', '2018-01-19', '2018-01-19', '2018-01-19',
               '2018-01-19', '2018-01-19'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='as_of_date', length=1722051, freq=None)
```

i ve tried to select 
`dfq['2018-01']` - works just fine 
but if i do 
`dfq['2018-01-19']` - got error - ok i assume its looking for column label

so what i did is 
`dfq.loc['2018-01-19']` - and its throwing an

```
'the label [2018-01-19] is not in the [index]'
```

i would expect pandas to be smart enough to cast literral as date and find it.
ofc its what i did manually like `dfq.loc[np.datetime64('2018-01-19')]`, but how can i do it properly - that is left it for pandas to do the work

Comment: Works when I tried it. Try upgrading pandas,

Comment: yeah, i ve closed env, reloaded data, and seems to works fine. on the first try i ve made some joins, reset on index and other changes on dataframe, one of those cases when 'something' went wrong